# how to properly match your own domain in "URL patterns to include" in jmeter script recorder

Tags: jmeter

our site makes 200+ requests.  about 100 are our own urls (images, css, js, fonts etc).  the other 100 are google analytics, newrelic, tealium, and lots of dross.

i want to match all, and only, requests to our site, which is [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com).

In "URLS Patterns to Include" I tried:

```
.*mysite.com.*
```

But this also includes many of the marketing requests which include the site name in the url parameters.

Next I tried this:

```
https:\/\/mysite.com.* 
https:\/\/www.mysite.com.*
```

but get no results back.

what is the proper way to include only, and all, resources loaded from your own domain?

I think this could be the way:

```
^www.mysite.com.*
```

It seems to return the right number of requests (when I clear cache before recording of course)

Is this the best solution?

Comment: `.*mysite.com.*` works for me, could you provide some screenshot of the configurations.

Comment: .*mysite.com.* also picks up several tealium and google analytics requests which have mysite.com in the get parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [ProxyControl.generateMatchUrl() function source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/proxy/ProxyControl.java#L1308) you will see the following:

```
private String generateMatchUrl(HTTPSamplerBase sampler) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(sampler.getDomain());
    buf.append(':'); // $NON-NLS-1$
    buf.append(sampler.getPort());
    buf.append(sampler.getPath());
    if (sampler.getQueryString().length() > 0) {
        buf.append('?'); // $NON-NLS-1$
        buf.append(sampler.getQueryString());
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Pay attention to this `sampler.getDomain()` bit which returns DNS hostname or IP address of the URL so if you add protocol there (`http` or `https`) the function will not match anything.

So you will have to provide patterns without protocol section like in the ["Suggested Excludes"](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/bin/templates/recording.jmx#L103)

[image]

If you have to include the protocol - I think you will need to re-consider your approach to recording and switch to i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) which provides possibility to filter the requests including the protocol:

[image]

Moreover you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, etc.